# images wont load properly

Tags: php, html

```
<?php include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/new/stations/includes/header.php"; ?> /* HEADER */
    <div class="content">
            <div class="content-padded">
                <!--     radio name     -->
                <h3 class="text-center"> Akwaaba Radio </h3>
                <!--     end radio name    -->
                <!--      start station logo       -->
                <div class="img-middle">
                    <img src="img/Akwaaba.png" alt="cmon" width="200px"> /* Station IMAGE*/
                </div>
                <!--      End Logo      -->
                <!--     Player       -->
                <div class="audio-player">
                    <p>Click the button ( <i class="fa fa-play"></i> ) to play</p>
                    <audio src="http://149.255.33.74:8002/;.mp3" controls="yes"></audio>
                </div>
                <!--     End Player       -->
                <!--            
 =================
navigation button
=================
-->
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <div class="text-center">

                <?php include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/new/stations/includes/toggle.php"; ?>

                </div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <!--
=================
navigation button
=================
-->
                <h4>About :-</h4>
                <!--      Station details      -->
                <div class="well">
                    001 (703) 395-0534
                </div>
                <!--      End Detials       -->
                <center>
                    <a class=" space-btn btn btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Share on Facebook</a>
                    <a class=" space-btn btn btn-twitter "><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> | Tweet on Twitter</a>
                    <a class=" space-btn btn btn-google-plus "><i class="fa fa-google"></i> | Share on google+</a>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </center>
                <!--      Adsense      -->
                <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/optimus_prime_hd-HD.jpg" width="100%">
                <!--      End Adsense      -->
                <!--      Phone Number       -->
                <a href="tel:001 (703) 395-0534" class="btn btn-positive btn-block space-btn">001 (703) 395-0534
                <br>
                <small>Station Hotline</small>
            </a>
                <!--      End Number      -->
                <div class="btm-spc"></div>
            </div>
        </div>"
<?php include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/new/stations/includes/footer.php"; ? >
```

In the above code image won't load at the first load. The page must refresh in order to load the image correctly. 
In desktop browsers the image does load at once but in mobile the Page must be refreshed to load the image.
 [Please Select the First Option](http://www.t.megaradio.lk/new/directory.php)

Comment: Which Image not loading?

Comment: the image at the top.  Please take a look at the code . i have commented it also

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<img src="img/Akwaaba.png">
```

with

```
<img src="<?php echo$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT];?>/img/Akwaaba.png">
```